# Can you map a fixed value using the standard BizTalk mapper

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

Normally, I create my BizTalk mappings in the XSL. Today I was playing around with the mapper but I am failing to do the most basic thing and googling it fails me (I find unrelated questions or the basic way to do it in XSL)

The question is simple though, I want to use the BizTalk mapper (btm file) to map one element to another and fill a second element with a fixed value.

Looking at the functoids, I have a date functoid which gets today's date but nothing to just type some text and map it.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "built in" way to do this is to set the **Value** property on the destination node in the map (you can also use this property to desginate that an empty node should be created for this destination node).  Unfortunately, this method offers no visual representation that the node is being set this way, except that it will prevent you from linking other nodes/functoids to that destination node.  This may lead future devs (or your future self) to think the node isn't being set, or be confused as to why it's being set when it has no inputs.

To get around this, I've frequently used either a String Concatenate functoid (with the fixed value as the only parameter, manually typed in) or a Value Mapping functoid (set "true" as the first parameter and the fixed value as the second parameter).  This offers a few benefits:

1. Visually shows that node is being set by the map
2. Allows you to set a meaningful label and/or comment on the functoid to denote why you're setting that value.